# Errors when I access "block" page on drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

Does anyone have any idea why I could be getting these errors when I access my "blocks" page?

> warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. warning:
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 3475. user
>   warning: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'tmd' query: INSERT INTO blocks
>   () VALUES () in /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc on line
>   3524.

Thank you!  If I'm not specific enough I'm sorry, I really have no idea what could cause this.

*Edit:  I am mostly hoping to find somebody else who has run into the same problem.

Comment: Did this happen after installing a module? See if there are any other warnings in watchdog as well

Comment: checkout what happens in common.inc on line 3524 and debug from there man

Comment: The error is definitely a faulty piece of code trying to use the wrong data-type in an assignment. This must be from either a new module or a piece of custom code you've written involving blocks. Definitely look at that line to begin the debug track. Also, as said above, what did you just install?